# Call to undefined function curl_init() PHP-Gtk

Tags: php, gtk, php-gtk

What I'm trying to do is creating a time tracker track time and saving it to server via curl

remaining part of application works fine but when I'm calling curl to submit time it shows me error "Call to undefined function curl_init()"

Comment: Is cURL enabled in `php.ini`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like `CURL` is not enabled. You can check this with a `phpinfo()` file.

What you need to do is edit the `php.ini` file and un-comment `;extension=php_curl.dll` (remove the `;`). Then restart your web server.

Comment: I'm creating desktop application and there's no php_curl extension in ext folder and after putting php_curl.dll it still show me error